# Trying to modify attribute combination to show one by one in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I´m working with PS 1.6.1.9

And I have add multiple attribute, some products have 2 options and some have 4.

One of the products have 4: modell, Consumption, Cooling capacity and Heat output.

And When I choose one of the modell: **1700** Then I only want the one that belongs to modell 1700 to show in the other dropdown.

Now I see all, for example in the Heat output I see 800w, 1200w, 3300w.
I only want to see 800w

[image]

Is there a java or something else that I can use to modify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in back office (administration). Go to Catalog -> Attributes and edit the attribute group you want to change. In the attribute type you can choose a drop down list, a radio button or a color/texture. If you choose a radio button, they will show side by side.
You could also change the theme template to show the radio buttons differently.

Btw, this is not a java related problem. Prestashop doesn't use java. Maybe you are confusing with javascript. But java and javascript are very different things.

Comment: Hello

But i only whant to show the one that belongs to the modell..
Not all..

I find this one, but doesent understand how it works..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721515/how-to-change-selected-attribute-via-javascript

Comment: When editing the product you set the product combinations. The attributes available for each product.

Comment: Yes i can see in BO, but the costumer doesent now witch one to choose.

Comment: And in this example do you only have combinations for the 800w? Or what combinations do you have for this model?

Comment: this combination do i have in the product.

Consumption - 620 w, Cooling capacity - 1700 w, Modell - 1700, Heat output - 800 w   

Consumption - 950 w, Cooling capacity - 2200 w, Modell - 2200, Heat output - 1200 w 

Consumption - 1200 w, Cooling capacity - 2800 w, Modell - 2600, Heat output - 3300 w